# Multiple imputation in longitudinal studies

Tags: panel-data, multiple-imputation

I am conducting a population-based study on the changes and stability of sexual identity (e.g., heterosexual, homosexual) over time. The study is based on a cohort of participants who were followed up over 11 years (three waves of surveys in 2010, 2014 and 2021). However, there are missing values in reporting sexual identity in each wave. I am wondering if it would be reasonable to consider using multiple imputation to impute the missing values in sexual identity.

However, multiple imputation imputes multiple values for each participant at each wave. Though each imputed dataset can be analysed separately to visualise the stability of sexual identity, in this case, I am not aware of methods of taking into account the uncertainty in the imputed values. This consideration prompts me to make a conclusion that multiple imputation is suitable for group level analysis, but not for individual level analysis (like in my situation).

Anyone who can give some comments/thoughts are highly appreciated!